# Add link to php field text on wordpress form

Tags: php, customization, urls, forms, links

I have bought a wordpress template but the developers say they cannot help me with what I need.

The theme has a hotel reservation system integrated, and the form brings a field to “place” the user email, however this option is disabled, only a Text appears that says “Need to be logged in” but when I click over there nothing happens.

I guess that email field should at least take me to a page (maybe user registration), or at least that's what I wish to happen.

I've been reviewing the PHP code of that form, but I really don't know what to do because I don't handle PHP, I don't know how I could solve this issue.

I tried several times to fix that by adding an a href= but nothing  happens.

Is there someone who could please help me or tell me what to do?

This is the code of that php field on the form:

```
<span class="mkdf-input-email">
                    <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Email:', 'mkdf-hotel' ) ?></label>
                    <input type="text" class="mkdf-res-email" name="user_email" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Need to be logged in', 'mkdf-hotel' ) ?>" disabled value="<?php echo esc_attr($email) ?>" />                    </span>
```

I would like to add this url link (https://www.mayanhills.com/cuenta-de-usuario) on the `Need to be logged in’ text field.

Here is the page link to see the form if you want to do that:

http://www.mayanhills.com/hotel-room/habitacion-sencilla/

Sorry about my english, hope somebody can understand and help me please.

Thank you so much

Comment: Looks like you need JavaScript/jQuery and not PHP. The input field is disabled, so the logic would be to (1) check if `input.mkdf-res-email` is disabled, and (2) if yes, then onclick go to the required href.

Comment: Thank you so much Pat, where can I check and edit that input to check if is disabled? I´m so sorry, I don´t know where to do that... I hope finding it maybe I could edit as you told me... Thanks a lot

Comment: answer below. Please update what worked - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your website works as it should be, because:

1. I see what you see, there's no way to book the room. [image: Booking]
2. To access to the booking functionality, you must to register your self at http://www.mayanhills.com/registro-de-nuevo-usuario/, there's a window like this one [image: Form].
3. Then you log in. [image: Login form]
4. Then you go back to the booking place... And there you go: [image]

I think it works perfect, now if you want to change that or at least send you to the registration form you should modify with PHP with something like this.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<span class="mkdf-input-email">
    <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Email:', 'mkdf-hotel' ) ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="mkdf-res-email" name="user_email" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Need to be logged in', 'mkdf-hotel' ) ?>" disabled value="<?php echo esc_attr($email) ?>" />
</span>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ); ?>" class="mkdf-res-email" alt="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'textdomain' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Login', 'textdomain' ); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope that helps you. ;D

**UPDATE**

With the code you sent me I did this:

```
<div class="mkdf-hotel-room-reservation" data-room-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
    <form id="mkdf-hotel-room-form" method="POST">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('mkdf_hotel_room_booking_form', 'mkdf_hotel_room_booking_form'); ?>
        <div class="mkdf-grid-row">
        
        <!-- New code -->
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : // Verify if current user is logged in, if so; show the input with the email. ?>
            <div class="mkdf-grid-col-12">
                <span class="mkdf-input-email">
                    <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Email:', 'mkdf-hotel' ) ?></label>
                    <input type="text" class="mkdf-res-email" name="user_email" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Need to be logged in', 'mkdf-hotel' ) ?>" disabled value="<?php echo esc_attr($email) ?>" />
                </span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif: // In case the current user is not known, show the registration link.  ?>
            <style>
                /* If possible, move these styles to the styles.css */
                .mkdf-unkown-user{
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 12px 40px;
                    font-family: inherit;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    line-height: 30px;
                    font-weight: inherit;
                    color: #afafaf;
                    background-color: transparent;
                    border: 1px solid #555;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="mkdf-grid-col-12">
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('descriurlption'); ?>/registro-de-nuevo-usuario/" class="mkdf-unkown-user" alt=""><?php _e( 'Login', 'textdomain' ); ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- End new code -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much @LaJennyLove This is a great help to me. The thing is I would like in the field where says ¨Need to be logged in¨ i want do a click to go to that login or registration page. I will try this... Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, with the code I left you here... First check if the user is logged in; in case the user is logged in, it shows the field as it should be, but if the user is not logged in, then it shows the link to go to the register page.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LaJennyLove I´m trying it right now, I´ll tell you anything. Again, thank you so much

Comment: This should will go to the wp-login.php page right? how can I do to go to this page: http://www.mayanhills.com/registro-de-nuevo-usuario

Comment: @Jeovanny Instead of use  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) ); ?>" class="mkdf-res-email" alt="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Login', 'textdomain' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Login', 'textdomain' ); ?></a> use this:  <a href=http://www.mayanhills.com/registro-de-nuevo-usuario/" class="mkdf-res-email" alt="Need to be logged in">Need to be logged in</a>

Comment: Hello again @LaJennyLove

Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it very much.

The code works perfect, the only detail is that the text loses its properties, is black and no longer appears in the box like the others.
Do you think I could be doing it wrong? Sorry to bother you so much.

You can look what Im talking about here:
http://www.mayanhills.com/hotel-room/cabanas/


Thank you help and the pacience

Comment: Please look this is the full code section for that field: https://bit.ly/3qLg5vI

Comment: Hi again, I edited your code just take a look how to paste it because it should replace the 12 grid div with the email input inside, and that's it. https://snipit.io/public/snippets/61871 if you still have questions look for me at https://twitter.com/JennyAstronauta

Comment: Thank you so much Jenny, I'll check if this works now

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the input field is disabled. This means the user is not logged in.

If it is disabled, then you add a link to the container using jQuery that, when clicked, will take the user to the registration/login page.

Put this javascript/jQuery at the bottom of your page to achieve this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        if ($("input.mkdf-res-email").prop('disabled')) {
            $("span.mkdf-input-email").on('click', function () {
                window.location.replace('http://www.mayanhills.com/registro-de-nuevo-usuario/');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```